# Assigning static constexpr member equal to static constexpr function?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class with a static constexpr array. I'd like to assign it equal to another class member function. Right now I have the current solution, but I feel it's pretty suboptimal, and the function is no longer scoped to the class.

```
static constexpr std::array<Degrees, 270> angles()
{
    std::array<Degrees, 270> angles;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < angles.size(); i++)
    {
        angles[i] = static_cast<double>(i - 90.0) * (std::numbers::pi / 180.0);
    };
    return angles;
}

class MyClass
{
    static constexpr std::array<Degrees, 270> angles = angles();
}
```

Is there a better approach for initialising a static constexpr class member to a function like this? Ideally I'd do this using a member function of `MyClass`, with the implementation defined in the .cpp instead of the header.

Comment: "equal to a function" or "equal to the result of a function call"?

Comment: And no, you can't hide implementation details of `constexpr` code from the public header file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your member to be `constexpr`, you have to put the initialization in the header file.

Regarding your initialization, you can *inline* the function call by exploiting a lambda like so:

```
class MyClass
{
    static constexpr auto angles = []
    {
        std::array<Degrees, 270> angles;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < angles.size(); i++)
        {
            angles[i] = static_cast<double>(i - 90.0) * (std::numbers::pi / 180.0);
        };
        return angles;
    }();
};
```

Comment: I'd `auto` the type of the variable. Keeps it a bit DRYer since it must be specified in the lambda anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica fixed